# Whats the best way to make collidable objects without Tile2D?

Tags: libgdx

I'm currently trying to make a small platformer, but don't want to use Tile2D (specific reasons), what should I use instead to make platforms (objects the player can collide with).

At the moment, I have a List with every Rectangle the player can collide with and I go through every Rectangle when I want to check collisions, but I find that to be very clunky.

What should I use to make platforms, the player etc. I haven't used Box2D yet, dont know if its the thing I need and am also not sure wether Scene2D is the thing I am looking for. Any tips would be appreciated. Not sure if this is the right place to post this, but its worth a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mix two things:

- **Box2D** is a physics engine that allows you to simulate physical world with its whole actions like collisions handling, applying forces or velocity etc
- **Scene2D** is a framework to "clean up" handling objects you want to manage - by definition it is scene graph that allows you to treat bunches of objects as single objects (groups) and apply for them some actions (like setting position on the screen)

So basically when Box2D is more about how objects will behave themselves during application running the Scene2D is more about how you write your code before application running.

Of course Scene2D is very helpful if you want to implement your own mechanism of collisions (like you wrote - you have rectangles array, then iterate over them and check their positions... etc) but the Box2D deliveres you this mechanism so you don't have to do nothing to check just tell the application what to do when collision will occurs.

Then it is problem about **is it worth to implement your own collisions mechanism**. The most frequent answer I guess is - **if the game is simple and the mechanism will be then yes**. If not just use physics engine - do not invent fire again ;)

To read about **Box2D** and learn how to use it visit:

- [Libgdx box2d intro](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Box2d)
- [Box2D official manual](http://box2d.org/manual.pdf)

To read about **Scene2D**:

- [Libgdx Scene2D intro](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d)
- [This tutorial](http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2013/11/27/LibGDX-Tutorial-9-Scene2D-Part-1.aspx)